# Setting line-height equal to font-size causes line height to increase radically

Tags: font-size, css

I was under the impression that line height would be slightly larger than font-size(about 20%). What I am seeing instead is that I have to set line height below that of font size to get a reasonable line height.

I need to set line-height manually for layout purposes. What am I doing wrong?

Here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BT2T/) showing huge line-height when font-size and line-height are the same.

In case fiddle goes down:

HTML:

```
<h2>Contact Me</h2>
<p>You can Contact Me at sample@smaple.com or use the contact form below:</p>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
    font-size:2em;
    line-height:2em;
    float: left;
    background-color:red;
}
p {
    background-color:yellow;
    font-size:2em;
    line-height:2em;
}
```

Comment: you've essentially set the line height to 200%, more often than not decent legibility looks for around a 1.5 line height or 1.5em. I am 99% sure that when working with ems you're essentially working with percentages. So 2em line height is calculated from the size of the type and not a set size.

Comment: They are not the same. Since the font size is 2em, the calculated line height (based on the font size) is twice the font size. [more about how em works](http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/)

Comment: Ok, I get it now line-height is relative to font-size. So I assume it is not possible to reliably set the height of a div equal to line height(without javascript)?

Comment: I've tested some fonts and it seems it should be possible sinze line height doesn't vary between fonts. Setting same line-height to <p> and <div> makes the div 1px taller, any ideas why?

Comment: You might want to improve your question by showing what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Question has been essentially answered (@Rick add your comment as an answer please). I would still like to know why a div with 2.6em height renders as 42px and h2 with line-height renders as 41px?

Comment: I found that the difference in height was due to browser rounding differences. Firefox rounded up, chrome rounded down from 41.6px